# Phil.SE Veterans: Does usage decline in the summer?

Tags: discussion

I've noticed two things in the last month or so. There seems to be less activity from a lot of our more veteran/expert users as well as a seeming decrease in site activity more generally.

Is this part of the normal ebb and flow of site use? Is this something others have noticed?

Comment: I can substantiate some of this; given the academic calendar it's perhaps not entirely unsurprising.

Comment: @JosephWeissman Yea, that was more or less what I had figured.

Answer (score 1):

It definitely does a little bit! Given the academic calendar I'm not entirely sure how worrying it might really be; it's a good time maybe to remember that people are always entering and leaving participation in different communities.

At any rate, I think it might be worth considering outreach efforts particularly in the summer; both to get members more deeply engaged in the community so they're likely to stay plugged-in even in the absence of a structured academic environment; and on the other hand to capture more incoming students' attention, if only to let them know that we are available as a resource.